# Insert FIX message with unicode delimiter in Scala

Tags: scala, unicode, fix-protocol

I am using a velocity template for a FIX message containing  `;` as the delimiter in the template file. I want to replace the  `;` with `\u000` character as delimiter when actualy publishing the message. 
  When I try `msg.replaceAll(";", "\u000")` , compiler complains "error in unicode escape"? 
What is the right way to do this in Scala?

Comment: `"foo;bar".replaceAll(";", """\\u000""")` => `foo\u000bar` is this what you wanted?

Comment: An extra 0 also seems to quieten the compiler complaint without the extra backslash - `"foo;bar".replaceAll(";", """\u0000""")` . I wonder which out of these would be correct for this message to be consumed correctly by downstream FIX clients?

Answer (score 0):

(edit)Escape backslash or use triplequotes like om-nom-nom advised:

```
msg.replaceAll(";", "\\\\u000")
```

or

```
msg.replaceAll(";", """\\u000""")
```